# Exploring org-mode outlines without Emacs

Tags: org-mode

I'm looking for a way to share `org-mode` outlines such that

- it is accessible to non-Emacs users;
- preserves as much of `org-mode`'s expand/collapse functionality as possible.

---

I know that one can export `*.org` files to, e.g., HTML, but I find that viewing such exports in a web browser is *far less useful* than viewing the original `org-mode` outline with Emacs.  With the export one gets "everything all at once", thereby losing the ability to selectively "zoom in and out of nodes", so to speak.

What I miss most are the following:

- the ability to expand and collapse headings;
- visibility cycling;
- `org-narrow-to-subtree`/`widen` (aka `C-x n s`/`C-x n w`)

Comment: Consider synchronizing with `org-toodledo` and giving the select group read-only access on the Toodledo website.  The aforementioned library can be modified (without too much trouble) to support all keywords and priorities, but the default behavior is just simple things like TODO and DONE.  I've been using a modified version of `org-toodledo` to run my small business and personal calendar for the past three years.  Toodledo has all kinds of ways to filter results.  In addition to the web interface, there are apps for most popular OS (desktop and hand-held).

Comment: It's too bad markdown wasn't available (or at least didn't have much visibility) when org-mode started. If org-mode used markdown format, there would be less friction sharing with folks who don't use Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

The best existing solution might be to upload the org-mode files to a Github repository. [Github supports org markup](https://github.com/github/markup#markups), so the files will automatically be rendered and appear in a formatted view. Your collaborator can then switch to `Raw` view to see the original unparsed org-mode source.

This still won't support org heading navigation or visibility cycling, however.

Answer (score 2):

Most of what you want is achievable by adding `#+INFOJS_OPT: view:info toc:nil` and exporting to html. Read the html export section of the  documentation for details